# Python _init() method in __init__.py

Tags: python

I read some code and found a `def _init()` method in the `__init__.py` file. It is not called anywhere in the file or any other files. So what's the purpose of this `_init()` method?
I understand that `_` prefix means the method is private in Python. But I don't know how `_init()` works in the `__init__.py` file without being called in any other file.

Comment: The _init() method is not defined in a class. It is a top level method.

Comment: Can you give an example of a package that contains this function?

Comment: You can choose function names (outside of classes) however you like (with the exception of language keywords, but you can choose the same name as any built-in), there is no semantic meaning to them.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I was suggested to use `_init` (by a LLM) to indicate to other developers that `__init__` should not be used directly. (Not super useful IMO if this isn't a widely known standard... is it?)

### Functionality of single underscore (already stated by OP)

In terms of purpose, the single underscore at the beginning of a method name in Python is a convention that indicates that the method is private, although it is not enforced. This means that the method should only be called by other methods in the same class.

I found another more in-depth answer about single underscore methods in python from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/13281260).

### Background on my Q/A

I ran across this when receiving a review from [coderabbitai](https://coderabbit.ai/). In my class, I have a classmethod which I intend to be the main method for creating an instance of my class. Coderabbitai suggested that I add the method

```py
def _init(self):
    pass
```

to my class to

> make the constructor private (i.e., rename `__init__` to `_init`). This would signal to other developers that they should use the `from_dict` method instead.

which led me here since I had never head of being able to "rename `__init__` to `_init`" (and we all know how well a LLM can BS). It turns out, it isn't actually renaming anything, but just acts as an indicator not to use the dunder method of the same name.

Anyway, I ended up searching "_init with single underscore in python" to double check nothing funky would happen which led me to some more conclusive answers.